# Trying to make my xAPI statement dynamic

Tags: tin-can-api

I have an application where someone logs in with their full name and email address. I capture that information with HTML5's local storage. I want to then use xAPI Youtube Video tracker to send messages to the LRS. I'm having trouble with the code that places the local storage variable into the actor statement. When I hard code a name and email address, it works fine. When I try and pull it from local storage it says "no way." Can you look at my offending code and tell me where I'm going wrong? I commented what does work and what doesn't work is right below it. Many thanks.

```
var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    var email = localStorage.getItem('email');  
    var video = "RXsHnGyVddg"; // Change this to your video ID

    // "global" variables read by ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements
    ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.changeConfig({
      //"actor":  {"mbox":"mailto:molly.fisher@example.com", "name":"Molly Fisher"},
      "actor":  {"mbox":"mailto:" + email, "name": + name},
      "videoActivity": {"id":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + video, "definition":{"name": {"en-US":video}} }
    });

    function initYT() {
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    }

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: video,
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0 },
        events: {
          'onReady': ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onPlayerReady,
          'onStateChange': ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onStateChange
        }
      });
    }

    initYT();


    // Auth for the LRS
    var conf = {
        "endpoint" : "https://lrs.adlnet.gov/xapi/",
        "auth" : "Basic " + toBase64("xapi-tools:xapi-tools"),
    };

    ADL.XAPIWrapper.changeConfig(conf);

    /*
     * Custom Callbacks
     */
    ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onPlayerReadyCallback = function(stmt) {
      console.log("on ready callback");
    }

    // Dispatch Youtube statements with XAPIWrapper
    ADL.XAPIYoutubeStatements.onStateChangeCallback = function(event, stmt) {
      console.log(stmt);
      if (stmt) {
        stmt['timestamp'] = (new Date()).toISOString();
        ADL.XAPIWrapper.sendStatement(stmt, function(){});
      } else {
        console.warn("no statement found in callback for event: " + event);
      }
    }
```

Comment: If you are seeing the literal string `no way` then this sounds more like a local storage question rather than a Tin Can one. Where are you seeing that string? Have you tried doing a `console.log(email);` and a `console.log(name);` to see what is in those two variables and/or set some breakpoints, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mean the actual words "no way." I meant that the statement was not working with what I tried. It works when I hard code a name in - it does not work when I try and reference a variable. Can you see any obvious problems with that one particular line of code? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems, other than if those values aren't being returned as you suspect from the `.getItem` call which is why I would suggest you add the logging. Additionally it would be helpful to look at the request body being sent to the LRS, to the response status code of the HTTP request, and to the body which likely contains more error information. You should be able to do all of that from the browser developer tools in any modern browser.